# spring xml config

Tags: java, spring

I have all my configuration details like (queries bean, url mapping etc) in one file (businesscaliber-servlet.xml) but i want separate out how do i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
<import resource="..."/>
```

See [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import). So in your `businesscaliber-servlet.xml` file, you could have:

```
<beans>
   <import resource="queries-bean.xml"/>
   <import resource="url-mappings.xml"/>

   ... etc ...
</beans>
```

Spring doesn't care which beans go into which file, they all get combined at runtime.